# Django SOAP client

Tags: django, soap

I need to implement a simple SOAP **server** for an external company to send me notifications.

They sent me a WSDL file. I started by trying to re-implement this file by writing the same models using [spyne](http://spyne.io). This is a tedious work.

Since I cannot define my own models (wsdl provided externally), is there a better way to do this ? I only have a couple RPC methods to implement.

Isn't it a way to use the WSDL file to parse a django request, extract what I need (method call and args) and build an appropriate response to their requests ?

The service must use plain SOAP request/response.

Comment: Your question is confusing. Is it a SOAP client you need, or a SOAP server? Is this external company sending notifications as specific SOAP requests and you need to process them and respond? Did I understand this correctly? Also, is this plain SOAP request/responses or do you need to implement other [WS-* specifications](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_web_service_specifications) as well?

Comment: I need a SOAP server to receive requests from the external company. Plain SOAP request/response.

Answer (score 1):

You basically have two options:

- use a SOAP library like spyne. As you already noticed this isn't much fun and tends to be a bit heavyweight (like tying your hand when it doesn't hurt kind of approach);
- do it "by hand".

What I mean with "by hand" is this: if the service you need to implement doesn't require other [WS-* specs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_web_service_specifications) (although if it did I doubt spyne could have helped much with that anyways) and it's just plain SOAP requests and responses, then you can treat them like HTTP POST requests with an XML payload because that's all they are. You receive an XML request and generate an XML response.

You can even use something like [lxml](https://lxml.de/) to validate the SOAP request against an XML schema just to make sure things are properly sent by the external company (you already have the XML schema of the elements and operations you want inside the WSDL they sent you, so you can copy those parts from there; adding the rules for the SOAP envelope will not be too difficult). You could use a simpler [SOAP library](https://wiki.python.org/moin/WebServices#SOAP) to build the messages or you can even implement a poor man's solution with string concatenation.

You don't need to implement the whole service from the WSDL you received, just use the WSDL as resource for how to properly format the XML messages. The rest is just handling HTTP requests and responses.